# Implementing a helper class in a header file

Tags: c++, inner-classes

say in a header file can I have a helper class fully defined and use it in the class file that includes the header. what is the correct way of doing it?
//HEader

```
class LinkedList() {
   public:
       LinkedList(int a);
   private:
      Node *root;
      class Node {
        int data;
        Node *next;
      };
};
```

//cpp file

```
#include "LinkedList"
LinkedList::LinkedList(int a) {
    root = new Node();
    root.data = a;
    root->next = NULL;
}
```

when i try doing something like that it ends up saying Node is not a name of type in my header file.

Comment: The problem lies not in your usage of Node .n the .cpp, but in your declaration of the field `Node* root` before you declare the Node class in your header.

Answer (score 1):

That is totally fine. I made some fixes to your code.

**LinkedList.h**

```
class LinkedList
{
  public:
       LinkedList(int a);
   private:
      class Node {
      public:
        int data;
        Node *next;
      };
      Node *root;
};
```

**LinkedList.cpp**

```
LinkedList::LinkedList(int a) {
    root = new Node();
    root->data = a;
    root->next = NULL;
}
```

You tried to use `Node` before you even declared and defined it. Default access level in C++ classes is private, so you could not access private data members of `Node` in `LinkedList` constructor.